# Was Lalitōpākhyānam not included in the Vāyu or in the Baṅgabāsi edition of the Brahmāṇḍa Purāṇa originally?

Tags: lalita

The following is an excerpt from Kamakotimandali Website:

> The Lalitōpākhyānam is a text containing 40 Chapters and comprising of about 3000 verses. At present, it is found included in the Brahmāṇḍa Purāṇa. The text of this upākhyāna has nothing to do with the rest of the Purāṇa.
>
> The Lalitōpākhyānam is neither found in the Vāyu, nor in the Baṅgabāsi edition of the Brahmāṇḍa Purāṇa, nor in the Javanese version. Insofar as this work is not included in the Vāyu Purāṇa, it could only prove that the same was added to the Brahmāṇḍa Purāṇa, at a time later than the compilation of the Vāyu text or else its inclusion in it might not even have been considered imperative from the sectarian point of view.
>
> The volume of the text of the Baṅgabāsi edition of the Brahmāṇḍa Purāṇa without the inclusion of either two of the Lalitōpākhyānam or the Adhyātma Rāmāyaṇa or the Bhārgavōpākhyānam, hardly answers the traditional bulk of the Purāṇa, 12000 verses recorded by the lists of as many as four different Purāṇas.
>
> http://www.kamakotimandali.com/blog/index.php?p=1537&more=1&c=1&tb=1&pb=1

My question is whether it is true that Lalitōpākhyānam was a subsequent addition to Vayu or Brahmanda Purana?